# Compiler Error - metadata operation failed

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I am getting this error:

```
    Joke.obj : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131187) : Inconsistent method declarations in duplicated types (types: SE.Crypt; methods: GetVolumeInformationA): (0x06000008).
    LINK : fatal error LNK1215: metadata operation failed (8013118A) :
```

Here is the code in the header file:

```
    private:
            [System::Runtime::InteropServices::DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            static Int64 GetVolumeInformation(String ^PathName, StringBuilder ^VolumeNameBuffer, UInt32 VolumeNameSize, UInt32 %VolumeSerialNumber, UInt32 %MaximumComponentLength, UInt32 %FileSystemFlags, StringBuilder ^FileSystemNameBuffer, UInt32 FileSystemNameSize);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`GetVolumeInformation` returns BOOL which does not map onto Int64.

By the way, when you call the ANSI version of this function, you might run into trouble.  When Windows 7 creates a system reserved partition, the installer gives it a volume name according to the installer's language, which doesn't have to match the environment that you'll be executing in.  It would be better to call the Unicode version.